# Can't see sonos devices on Spotify connect

Tags: python, spotify, sonos, tekore

I am trying to connect my Spotify to my sonos. I am using the Tekore library to consume the Spotify API. When I try to list all devices on Spotify Connect, i.e. `spotify.playback_devices()`, I get only some of the available devices. Especially, the Sonos devices are not listed. Does anybody know why?

Comment: "*I get only some of the available devices. Especially, the Sonos devices are not listed*" Can you clarify if "*some of the available devices*" includes Sonos or not? It's really not clear from the way you've phrased this.

Comment: Is your Sonos system up-to-date? [This Sonos KB article](https://support.sonos.com/s/article/1153?language=en_US) seems to think that older versions of software in the stack can contribute to Sonos devices not appearing in Spotify Connect. Have your Sonos devices ever appeared in Spotify Connect?

Comment: in the spotify app, I can see the sonos devices. But when I query the devices through Tekore, no Sonos device appears in the list of devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/using-connect-web-api/#devices-not-appearing-on-device-list) for the Spotify Connect Web API is pretty clear about this type of scenario:

> #### Devices not Appearing on Device List
>
> Connect Web API relies on local network connections to discover and interact with some devices.
>
> For example, when:
>
> - A new device is added to the network
> - A device is in “sleep” mode
> - A device on the local network is currently tied to another user account, or
> - Other reasons specific to the device
>
> As a result, some devices that appear in the Connect picker within the
> Spotify application may not always be visible or available on the
> [Connect Web API
> Endpoints](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/using-connect-web-api/#devices-not-appearing-on-device-list).

Translation: if it doesn't appear in the API, there's likely a reason for that. You might be able to get further guidance from the development team if you tweet at them [@SpotifyPlatform](https://twitter.com/SpotifyPlatform).

Comment: hmm, must have skipped that part, but yes, that probably answers my question, thanks

Comment: according to the spotify web api github issues (e.g. https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/525), sonos devices are "restricted" and cannot be controlled through the connect API. bummer :-/